# Remove letters that occur twice in a row?

Tags: python, string

So I am generating a random name but sometimes some of the name will look a bit like this:
'bbob' So I would like to delete the letters in the string to make is look like this:
'bob'. Now I know how to delete all duplicates of a certain letter in a string but I only want to get rid of letters that occur two times in a row. But of course keep one of them. Here is what I have done so far.

```
def Gen():
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase[:-3].replace('q','')
    print(letters)
    passed = False
    while passed == False:
        vowels = 4
        consanants = 2
        consanantCount = 0
        vowelCount = 0
        name = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(vowels+consanants))
        for letter in name:
            if letter in 'aeiou':
                vowelCount +=1
            else:
                consanantCount +=1
        if vowelCount == vowels and consanantCount == consanants:
            passed = True
        else:
            passed = False
    return name
print(Gen())
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: This can also be done with a regex and a reference to a capture group: /(.)\1+/$1/ (adapt to Python usage..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I see what you are trying to do. So what I would do is try something like this. It will get rid of letters that repeats but only if they are seen in a row:

**Input:**

```
reps = 1   # number of consecutive repeated chars allowed
name = 'ttomt'
name = ''.join(['' if i>reps-1 and e==name[i-reps] else e for i,e in enumerate(name)])
```

**OutPut:**
`tomt`

Hopefully this was helpful!

Comment: You've expanded the scope of the problem by adding the reps variable, which is the "maximum repeats" of a character.  I think that merits a comment in the code in this case.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by your last line?

Comment: The simple answer would not have needed the reps variable.  Since you added it, I thought a comment after it,  such as  `reps = 1   # number of consecutive repeated chars allowed` would be helpful.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean :D Sure I could edit my post.